# Dockerfile - deploy MEAN to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cli

I have built a mean app and I would like to deploy it on Amazon using EB CLI.

I execute
    eb create

but it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to pull Docker image dockerfile/nodejs:latest: Pulling repository dockerfile/nodejs
time="2015-07-10T17:58:58Z" level="fatal" msg="Error: image dockerfile/nodejs:latest not found" . Check snapshot logs for details.
```

My dockerfile first line looks like:

```
FROM dockerfile/nodejs
```

That is where the error lays but I have no idea what image I should use for AWS. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository `dockerfile/nodejs` has been deprecated.

You can instead use `FROM node:latest` instead of `FROM dockerfile/nodejs`

`node` is the official repository for nodejs.

Here is the link to the official repo page for node:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/node/

And here is the open github issue for dockerfile/nodejs not found:
https://github.com/dockerfile/nodejs/issues/11

Comment: thanks, that installed the machine correctly, but the server is not firing up, it's another problem now though.